# Higher order function: "Cannot invoke 'map' with an argument list of type '((_) -> _)'"

Tags: swift, higher-order-functions

I would like to use a swift higher order function (map) to remove all Subviews from a given UIView.subviews array. The line

```
(cell.contentView.subviews as [UIView]).map { $0.removeFromSuperView() }
```

causes the error 
"Cannot invoke 'map' with an argument list of type '((_) -> _)'"

I would like to know what the compiler needs from me at this point.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I would say that map is not for this kind of operation. It creates a new sequence based on an others sequences elements, but what you don't want to create a sequence, you just want to iterate through them and apply a function to them. In swift there is no higher order function that matches what you want, I hope they will put something in soon. So the best you can do is to use a for loop or write your own function which does what you want.

I would like to suggest to write your own functon (based on what scalas foreach is):

```
extension Array {

    func foreach(function: T -> ()) {
        for elem in self {
            function(elem)
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATED with Swift 2.0**

[`forEach`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_SequenceType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/SequenceType/s:FPSs12SequenceType7forEachuRq_S__Fq_FFqqq_S_9GeneratorSs13GeneratorType7ElementT_T_) added to the `SequenceType`, so it is available:

```
(cell.contentView.subviews as [UIView]).forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
```

Comment: Agreed. This is a misuse of map. Map is not a universal replacement for for-in.

Comment: Okay, agreed. Somewhere along the road I read to not use higher order functions for their side effects.