# Swift map semantics

Tags: swift

I have the following code.

```
        let v_blue = UIView()
        v_blue.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        let v_red = UIView()
        v_red.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        let v_green = UIView()
        v_green.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
```

then doing: (Since `[].iter` doesn't exist, I'm doing a map just for side effects)

```
[v_blue, v_red, v_green].map({
    (v: UIView) in
    v.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)})
```

works correctly, but the following doesn't.

```
 [v_blue, v_red, v_green].map({
            (v: UIView) in
            v.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
            self.view.addSubview(v)})
```

With an error of "Cannot invoke 'map' with an argument list of type '(UIView) -> _)"

Okay fine, then I tried

```
[v_blue, v_red, v_green].map({
            (v: UIView) in
            v.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
            self.view.addSubview(v)
            return ()}) // return v also doesn't work
```

Which still doesn't work as I get the same error. I'm confused by this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell the compiler that the closure does not return a value:

```
[v_blue, v_red, v_green].map({
    v -> Void in
    v.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    self.view.addSubview(v)
})
```

The compiler infers the return type automatically from the *closure*
only if the closure consists of a single expression. And the compiler cannot
infer the return type from the *context* here.

The following would compile and work (but this is only meant as a demonstration
of type inference, *not* as a suggestion!!):

```
let _ : [()] = [v_blue, v_red, v_green].map({
    v  in
    v.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    self.view.addSubview(v)
})
```

Now the return value of `map()` is assigned to an array of `Void`, therefore the
compiler can infer the type of the closure as `UIView -> Void`.

---

**But actually,** using `map()` for this purpose seems to be frowned upon.
Compare [Higher order function: "Cannot invoke 'map' with an argument list of type '((_) -> _)'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28659616/higher-order-function-cannot-invoke-map-with-an-argument-list-of-type), where
an alternative is suggested:

```
[v_blue, v_red, v_green].foreach { v in
    v.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    self.view.addSubview(v)
}
```

with a custom extension

```
extension Array {

    func foreach(function: T -> ()) {
        for elem in self {
            function(elem)
        }
    }
}
```

And here the compiler infers the return type from the *context*: 
The closure's type is declared as `T -> ()` in the `foreach()` method.

Comment: I don't understand the first part,  `(v: UIView) -> Void`, I explicitly gave return () and it still didn't work, then I guess the compiler can't figure out the return value even when the return value is given.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian: The compiler infers the return type of the closure automatically *only* if the closure consists of a *single* expression. That's why your first example works and the second does not. – The `foreach()` method works because there the compiler can infer the return type from the *context*.

Answer (score 2):

Using `map` purely for side-effects is generally considered bad form – use use a `for…in` loop instead:

```
for view in [v_blue, v_red, v_green] {
    view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    // etc
}
```

Aside from being better stylistically, the reason to not use `map` just for looping purposes is that `map` creates an array – that’s its purpose.  So the closure you pass it must return a value.

This is why your second example doesn’t work – when a closure contains only one expression, the result of that expression is returned implicitly from the closure.  So your `map` is creating an array of type `[Void]`.

But when there are two or more expressions in the closure, you must put in an explicit return.  So this should work:

```
[v_blue, v_red, v_green].map { (view: UIView)->Void in
    view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    self.view.addSubview(view)
    return ()
}
```

The extra typing should resolve any problems with ambiguity you might hit (is the array of views a `[UIView]` or an `NSarray`?) that are the cause of the problems in the last example.

But hopefully its clear at this point that you do not want to be using `map`.  You could write a `foreach` method as an extension to array but, honestly, what is the point?  Just use a for loop.

Comment: bad form according to what? Iter doesn't exist so map is close enough.

Comment: "Using map purely for side-effects is generally considered bad form" Well, I don't agree. Apple gives an example in the Swift book - `map(println)` - so it's their own fault. And if they didn't want me to misuse `map` in this way, they should have given me a separate `each`. But hey, you and I sometimes don't agree; I have no problem with that.

Comment: I'm definitely with Airspeed Velocity on that. `map` should not have side effects. That why `for-in` exists.

Comment: @matt Personally I think that example from the official Swift book is a very bad influence :)   `println` is relatively benign but when reading code, there is an implicit suggestion that all `map` is used for is transformation to a different kind of array, and not general stateful looping.  If someone reading your code saw a mapping operation, but actually the map function was performing some kind of side-effect, they might be in for a nasty shock.

Comment: I actually gave the explicit return of () in my original post and it also doesn't work.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian `SequenceType.generate()` is the Swift equivalent of iterators from other languages, and is what `for…in` uses under the hood.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian I suspect you are getting hit by type inference ambiguity (the error messages about which are quite often very mystifying in Swift :).  I’ve edited my answer with a more explicitly typed version that might fix the problems you’re having...