# Swift Functional Programming - is there a better way to translate a nested for loop than two map calls

Tags: ios, swift, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

i've transformed a nested `for` loop into a nested `map` call. i was wondering if there was a more elegant way to implement it.

here is a function that takes in an `Array` of `Item`s and an `Array` of functions (`Item -> Item`) and returns an array with all of the functions applied to each item:

```
typealias Item = Dictionary<String, String>    

func updatedItems(items: Array<Item>, fns: Array<Item -> Item>) -> Array<Item> {
    return items.map {
        item in

        var itemCopy = item
        fns.map { fn in itemCopy = fn(itemCopy) }

        return itemCopy
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inner `map()` call does not return a new array, it is done merely for the side-effects. This works, but is sometimes "frowned-upon" (see
for example [Higher order function: "Cannot invoke 'map' with an argument list of type '((_) -> _)'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28659616/higher-order-function-cannot-invoke-map-with-an-argument-list-of-type)).

The "proper" way to apply all functions in turn to a single item is
to use `reduce`:

```
func updatedItems(items: Array<Item>, fns: Array<Item -> Item>) -> Array<Item> {
    return items.map {
        item in
        fns.reduce(item) {
            (curItem, fn) in
            fn(curItem)
        }
    }
}
```

or with shorthand argument names:

```
func updatedItems(items: Array<Item>, fns: Array<Item -> Item>) -> Array<Item> {
    return items.map {
        fns.reduce($0) { $1($0) }
    }
}
```

Note also that you can shorten the array notation to

```
func updatedItems(items: [Item], fns: [Item -> Item]) -> [Item] { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use `enumerate` in order to also have access to the index.

```
return items.enumerate().map { (idx, item) in
   let fn = fns[idx] as <Item -> Item>
   return fn(item)
}
```